# Crawl data using Scrapy+Selenium+PhantopJS lost data

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler, scrapy

I try to crawl the table data from http://www.sse.com.cn/assortment/stock/list/share/ which is **AJAX** pages.My code is following:

```
import scrapy

class GovSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gov'

    url = "http://www.sse.com.cn/assortment/stock/list/share/"

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
    }

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Users/luozhongjin/ScrapyDemo/ScrapyDemo/phantomjs')
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = self.url, headers = self.headers,callback = self.parse);

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
        i = 1
        while True:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            trs = soup.findAll("tr")
            for tr in trs:
                try:
                    tds = tr.findAll("td")
                    print tds
                    item = GovSpiderItem()
                    item["name"] = tds[1].string
                    print ("ok")
                    yield item
                except:
                    pass
            try:
                next_page = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("glyphicon-menu-right").click()
                i = i + 1
                if i >= 55:
                    break
            except:
                break
```

But when it finished, I check the json file and found that it lost data, that is to say, I need all of 54 pages data, but it sometimes just saves 53 pages data, sometimes 52 pages data or even much less.in my different test. But I add the line

```
time.sleep(3)
```

at the end of the while loop of parse function, it works. But I don't know why it works. I guess it might be the ajax request didn't finish without time delay, which leads to the loss of data. So I add the follow line to test

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

This line is used for waiting ajax request finished. But it didn't work. Can somebody tell me why I lost data? And is there an simple ways to crawl ajax pages with Scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.active` is the number of current AJAX requests. So the driver will wait the ajax requests to complete. But it will take some time to parse response and render the data.

```
ajax complete -> render the data -> html source updated
```

If driver tries to get source before rendering is completed, it will lose some data. I would choose a condition to check the element value. Here I maintain a current max stock id and since all data is in ascending order, new data must be greater than it:

```
return current_max_id < parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].children[0].text);
```

Another possible reason for the data loss is that `driver.implicitly_wait(15)` may not work here as described by documentation:

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount
>   of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately
>   available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is
>   set for the life of the WebDriver object.

Here you are feeding `driver.page_source` into `BeautifulSoup` instead of `driver.find_xxx`, so the `driver.implicitly_wait(15)` will not be triggered and it may skip the page 1. Here I would use another condition to check:

```
return document.getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0;
```

Test code:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class GovSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gov'

    url = "http://www.sse.com.cn/assortment/stock/list/share/"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        i = 1
        current_max = 0

        self.driver.get(response.url)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            lambda driver: self.driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0;'))

        while True:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            trs = soup.findAll("tr")
            for tr in trs:
                try:
                    tds = tr.findAll("td")
                    stock_id = int(tds[0].string)
                    current_max = max(current_max, stock_id)
                    yield {
                        'page num': i,
                        'stock id': tds[0].string
                    }
                except:
                    pass
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("glyphicon-menu-right").click()

                js_condition_tpl = 'return {} < parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].children[0].text);'
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    lambda driver: self.driver.execute_script(js_condition_tpl.format(current_max)))

                i = i + 1
                if i >= 55:
                    break
            except:
                break
```

PS: if you only need the data itself, there's a `xls` download link in the page which is a more robust and easy way to get the data.